# liquibase with long running statement

Tags: informix, liquibase

After working with Liquibase in several projects, last week I start using it with Informix. For every command executed either update or rollback, I have to wait about 1 minute for the results. With the help of wireshark, I detect, that Liquibase executes the following SQL statement and that statements needs so much time. is it possible to avoid that statement or made it faster ?

> SELECT trim(t.owner)::VARCHAR(128), t.tabname::VARCHAR(128), c.colname::VARCHAR(128),informix.get_data_type(c.coltype, c.extended_id, 0)::SMALLINT, informix.schema_coltypename(c.coltype,c.extended_id)::VARCHAR(128),informix.schema_precision(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength)::INTEGER, 0::INTEGER,informix.schema_numscale(c.coltype, c.collength)::INTEGER, informix.schema_numprecradix(c.coltype)::INTEGER,informix.schema_isnullable(c.coltype)::INTEGER, NULL::VARCHAR(254),CASE d.type   WHEN 'L' THEN informix.get_default_value(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength, d.default::lvarchar(256))::VARCHAR(254) WHEN 'C' THEN 'current'::VARCHAR(254)   WHEN 'S' THEN 'dbservername'::VARCHAR(254)   WHEN 'U' THEN 'user'::VARCHAR(254) WHEN 'T' THEN 'today'::VARCHAR(254) ELSE    NULL::VARCHAR(254) END,c.coltype::INTEGER, informix.schema_datetype(c.coltype, c.collength)::INTEGER, informix.schema_charlen(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength)::INTEGER,c.colno::INTEGER, informix.schema_nullable(c.coltype)::VARCHAR(3), NULL::VARCHAR(128), NULL::VARCHAR(128), NULL::VARCHAR(128), NULL::smallint, informix.schema_isautoincr(c.coltype)::VARCHAR(3),c.extended_id::INTEGER FROM informix.systables t,    OUTER informix.sysdefaults d, informix.syscolumns c     WHERE t.tabid = c.tabid and d.tabid = t.tabid      AND c.colno = d.colno   AND (t.tabtype not in ('P', 'S'))      AND (d.class in ('T'))    AND t.tabname like '%'    AND t.owner like 'informix' and c.colname like '%' union SELECT trim(st.owner)::VARCHAR(128),  st.tabname::VARCHAR(128),    c.colname::VARCHAR(128),   informix.get_data_type(c.coltype,c.extended_id, 0)::SMALLINT,    informix.schema_coltypename(c.coltype,c.extended_id)::VARCHAR(128),  informix.schema_precision(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength)::INTEGER,   0::INTEGER,   informix.schema_numscale(c.coltype, c.collength)::INTEGER,    informix.schema_numprecradix(c.coltype)::INTEGER,   informix.schema_isnullable(c.coltype)::INTEGER,   NULL::VARCHAR(254),   CASE d.type      WHEN 'L' THEN informix.get_default_value(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength, d.default::lvarchar(256))::VARCHAR(254)     WHEN 'C' THEN 'current'::VARCHAR(254) WHEN 'S' THEN 'dbservername'::VARCHAR(254) WHEN 'U' THEN 'user'::VARCHAR(254)      WHEN 'T' THEN 'today'::VARCHAR(254)      ELSE     NULL::VARCHAR(254)    END,   c.coltype::INTEGER,    informix.schema_datetype(c.coltype, c.collength)::INTEGER,    informix.schema_charlen(c.coltype, c.extended_id, c.collength)::INTEGER,   c.colno::INTEGER,    informix.schema_nullable(c.coltype)::VARCHAR(3),    NULL::VARCHAR(128),    NULL::VARCHAR(128),    NULL::VARCHAR(128),    NULL::smallint,   informix.schema_isautoincr(c.coltype)::VARCHAR(3),    c.extended_id::INTEGER   FROM informix.systables st, informix.syssyntable s, informix.systables t,     OUTER  informix.sysdefaults d,  informix.syscolumns c       WHERE st.tabid = s.tabid       AND s.btabid = t.tabid    AND t.tabid = c.tabid    AND d.tabid = t.tabid       AND c.colno = d.colno       AND (st.tabtype in ('P', 'S'))       AND (d.class in ('T'))       AND st.tabname LIKE '%'      AND st.owner LIKE 'informix' AND c.colname LIKE '%' order by 1,2,16

Comment: I believe the Informix DBA should help you. Probably the environment is overloaded or statistics is missing at these tables...

Answer (score 0):

running it on my instance (ids 12.10uc5) give me :

```
dbaccess stores lq.sql
real    0m0.701s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.032s
```

it not seems too slow for me, what is yours times ? the schema of the system tables can't be modified with adding/removing indexes. May be you could try a different/more recent Informix version ?
regards,